# Spring boot 2 - Actuator endpoint, where is /beans endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot 2 application I'm trying to access actuator endpoint /beans as I did before in Spring boot 1.5.* applications. But I'm unable to.
Also, I don't see the endpoint is being created in the log.INFO.

My pom.xml contains:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

in application.properties I only have info about the databaseconnectivity:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb
spring.datasource.username=someuser
spring.datasource.password=somepass
```

As mapped endpoints I see in the info logs:

```
/actuator/health
/actuator/info
/actuator
```

The application is working but no /application/beans endpoint is created.

How come my /beans or /application/beans endpoint is not generated and what should I change to make it exist?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the reference documentation this endpoint is no longer exposed via "web" by default.

First, you need to make sure that the "beans" endpoint is actually enabled:

```
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true
```

in your spring-boot-configuration. Then, you need to include it in the "web" exposure:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=beans
```

or maybe even

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints for further information.

Comment: This certainly put me in the right direction. I found that, to see it in my browser, I had to put `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=beans`. And this makes `management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true` redundant?

Comment: You're right! I updated my answer to make it easier to find the correct information for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for the yaml specification, for Spring Boot **v2.7.1**,

```
 management:
  endpoint:
    beans:
      enabled: true   
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: beans
```